# Is this chrome bug with select?

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome

Some extrange behaviour happen in Chrome.

https://codepen.io/wilcus/pen/WNrbVyE

```
class Select extends React.Component {
  state = {
    options: ['a']
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        options: ['d', 'b', 'c'],
      })
    }, 5000)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{'width': '300px'}}>
      <select style={{'width': '100%'}}>
        {this.state.options.map((option) => {
          return (
            <option>
              {option}
            </option>
          )
        })}
      </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I use react to update the options in combo.
Here are the steps:

1. Click combo and wait.
2. New values appear after some seconds.
3. Combo does not update the height.

After some seconds the bad behaviour:

[image: after some seconds]

The behaviour i want:

[image: good behaviour]

I try firefox and works.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the bug in chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=753001